# ScrollViewNot scrolling when text in label is larger than screen

Tags: swift

I have a screen where I want to show an image, the image title and the image description underneath and if the description is long you can scroll down to see the rest, but if its short it hugs up under the title

Currently i have:

```
  private let scrollView = UIScrollView()
  private let contentView = UIView()
  private let imageView = UIImageView()
  private let nameLabel = UILabel()
  private let descriptionLabel = UILabel()

    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.addSubview(imageView)
    contentView.addSubview(nameLabel)
    contentView.addSubview(descriptionLabel)

    scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    scrollView.contentSize = view.frame.size

    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    nameLabel.font = .characterTitle
    nameLabel.textColor = .textColor
    nameLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    nameLabel.sizeToFit()

    descriptionLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
    descriptionLabel.font = .characterDescription
    descriptionLabel.textColor = .textColor
    descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0

  private func layoutScrollView() {
    scrollView.pin(toSuperviewSafeArea: .top, .trailing, .bottom, .leading)
    contentView.pin(toSuperviewSafeArea: .top, .trailing, .bottom, .leading)
  }

  private func layoutImageView() {
    imageView.pin(toSuperviewSafeArea:  .top, .trailing, .leading)
  }

  private func layoutNameLabel() {
    nameLabel.pin(.top,
                  to: .bottom,
                  of: imageView,
                  constant: Spacings.margin)
    nameLabel.pin(.leading,
                  to: .leading,
                  of: contentView,
                  constant: Spacings.margin)
    nameLabel.pin(.trailing,
                  to: .trailing,
                  of: contentView,
                  constant: Spacings.margin)
  }

  private func layoutDescriptionTextView() {
    descriptionLabel.pin(.top,
                         to: .bottom,
                         of: nameLabel,
                         constant: Spacings.CharacterDetailsView.descriptionBottomMargin)
    descriptionLabel.pin(.leading,
                         to: .leading,
                         of: contentView,
                         constant: Spacings.margin)
    descriptionLabel.pin(.trailing,
                         to: .trailing,
                         of: contentView,
                         constant: Spacings.margin)
    descriptionLabel.pin(.bottom,
                         to: .bottom,
                         of: contentView,
                         constant: Spacings.margin)
  }
```

This works fine if the description is short, but if th description goes longer than the screen it doesnt show the title label anymore, the image shrinks and there is no scrolling.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, i just set my width and height of my scroll view bigger